# How to check if an item is in multiple Lists Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter method that places `Map Markers`

When one is pressed it pops up with a metadata box

Depending on which type of marker is pressed I will trigger a different `ShowDialog`

I have a Gesture Handler that listens for taps and then reacts.

Currently, upon tap it then calls  `_pickMapMarker(touchPoint);` which allows the metadata to show

I need a `_pickMapMarker2` to be an option depending on the type of marker pressed

All markers are added to a list, `List<MapMarker> _x` when placed, there is list `_mapMarkertype1`, `_mapMarkertype2`

I guess I will need an `if` or `for` statement but I cannot work it out dependant on the `List<MapMarker>` the marker belongs to

Currently

```
 void _setTapGestureHandler() {
    _hereMapController.gestures.tapListener = TapListener((Point2D touchPoint) {
     
      _pickMapMarker(touchPoint);
     });
  }
```

I need something like (It is of course not functional, just to explain what I need)

```
  void _setTapGestureHandler() {
    _hereMapController.gestures.tapListener = TapListener((Point2D touchPoint) {
     
      if (MapMarker == _mapMarkerList1) {
      _pickMapMarker(touchPoint);
      }
      if (MapMarker == _mapMarkerList2) {
      _pickMapMarker2(touchPoint);
      }

     });
  }
```